# Transfer data object between components Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I am trying to share information between component.

Is there another way to share the information with another component?

**My component SportComponent**

```
export class SportsComponent implements OnInit {

    _sportId: any;
    sportSummary: any[] = [];
    sportGroup: any[] = [];

    @Output() public SportGroupId: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor(private _service: SportsService, private _routeParams: RouteParams) {
        this._sportId = this._routeParams.get("id");
        this.SportGroupId.emit(this.sportGroup);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        // Payload to cal  the API
        var model: SportsPayload = {
            SportId: this._sportId
        }

        // Api loading
        Observable.forkJoin(
            this._service.getList(model)
        )
            .subscribe(
            res => {
                this.sportSummary = res[0];
                this.sportGroup = res[0].SpID;
            }
            )
    }

}
```

**Second Component**

```
export class SportsComponentList {
    @Input() SportGroupId;
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.SportGroupId)
    }
}
```

Comment: How are these components related?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#

Comment: @GünterZöchbauerIn the second component I have an `@Input SportGroupId` but when I check on Augury say that the emitter is empty. :(

Comment: This doesn't help me to understand how the components are related.

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer means we need to know if componentA is the parent/child/sibling of componentB or do they have other kind of relationship. Communication between parent/child components is different to communication between 2 separate components in 2 totally different packages.

Comment: @HarryNinh Thanks Mate. there are two separated components but they are not related like parent/child/siblings. I created a `@Input` in my second component 'SportsComponentList' but when I check on the console say that is underfined.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer sorry for that. I updated the code on the question with the input and output

Comment: What's the problem with `@Output()`? What problem are you trying to solve? I don't get what the question is about. That you are using `@Output()` seems to indicate that the elements are direct parent/child but there is no way to be sure.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer even when sportGroup has info, when I try to create the emitter `this.SportGroupId.emit(this.sportGroup);` the data is empty. I don't know what i am doing wrong

Comment: `@Output()` and `@Input()` don't match by itself. You need to use something like `<child (SportGroupId)="SportGroupId = $event"`. Please read the doc I linked to in my 2nd comment.